# How to run multiple color recognition with a user input?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I have a school project where I have to make a line following car that has to follow a specific color line depending on the user input. The code works fine when I test the car's line following capabilities with just one color and no user input, but when I add multiple colors and the user input, the car no longer wants to follow a line and just drives off into the sunset. I have tried to experiment with the code but no luck. This is the while loop of the code.

```
try:
    while(True):
        user = int(input("1 for blue line"))
        time.sleep(1)

        ret, frame = cap.read()

        crop_img = frame[60:120, 0:160]

        _, img = cap.read()

        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Tracking blue color

        if user == 1:
            blue_lower = np.array([99,115,150],np.uint8)
            blue_upper = np.array([110,255,255],np.uint8)
            blue = cv2.inRange(hsv, blue_lower, blue_upper)
            kernal = np.ones((5 ,5), "uint8")
            blue=cv2.dilate(blue,kernal)
            res=cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = blue)

            (contours,hierarchy)=cv2.findContours(blue,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

            for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
                area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
                if(area>300):

                        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                        img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

            Controls()

# Tracking black color

        else:
            black_lower = np.array([0,0,0],np.uint8)
            black_upper = np.array([50,50,100],np.uint8)
            black = cv2.inRange(hsv, black_lower, black_upper)
            kernal = np.ones((5 ,5), "uint8")
            black = cv2.dilate(black,kernal)
            res2 = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = black)

            (contours,hierarchy)=cv2.findContours(black,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

            for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
                area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
                if(area>300):

                        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                        img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

            Controls()
```

Comment: Do you see that the 11-12 lines following `cv2.inRange()` are repeated? That's because the colour only affects the limits of the range and not the code following, so you will make a maintenance nightmare if you code like that. Don't repeat unnecessary code, if you finally end up supporting 12 colours you will have 12 blocks of identical stuff to maintain. Let the colour the use selects affect the lower and upper ranges only, leave the dilation and contour finding in there just once after the ranges are set.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is due to the user input, although that depends on how `Controls()` is implemented. `input()` is a blocking call, meaning the program stops executing until the user presses enter. So, I think your code does this: when you give an input, an image is processed and the car is put in motion. The purpose is then to process a new image and alter the direction of the car if necessary. However, program execution hangs on the `input()`, so no new image is processed, and the car keeps driving in a straight line, because `Controls()` is never called/altered.

The solution is to place the `input()` outside of the `while`-loop. Now the car should be able the follow the blue line again. Note that you will now have to restart the script to follow a different color.

Lastly, as @Mark-Setchell comments, you make your life a lot easier when you use functions instead of repeating a bunch of code. In your case, you can make a function with the lower and upper colors as parameters. You can learn about functions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp).